# HTTP request header missing "cookie" from prod server, but includes from local environment

Tags: php, http-headers, apache2, session-cookies

I have a web app that uses PHP session cookies. I have this app running on a cloud LAMP server and on my desktop with MAMP. I'm providing access to this app via an iframe on another website with a different domain. The app works fine on FF and Safari, but I'm getting an issue on chrome. If I set the iframe to point to my local MAMP environment, the iframe receives "cookie" in http request header, and works fine, but if I set it to my prod server, the request header is missing "cookie." Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running it from your production server you have a 3rd party cookie and I'm guessing you would have the same issue on IE.

You need a P3P policy in place:
http://www.w3.org/P3P/usep3p.html

Google found a way to cheat so check this out, it may help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/20/google-bypassing-user-privacy-settings.aspx

Comment: Also suggest reading about same origin policy as relates to iFrames.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe